Downloading excel file from office365 gets saved as a webpage rather than excel
I am writing code to download an excel file which I further work on in python using openpyxl. I am downloading the file from the sharepoint url. It doesnt open if I save it as xlsx but if I save it as html , the excel opens in the browser as a webpage.
My Code:
def get_excel_from_link(url=None):
    user_credentials = UserCredential(username, password)
    ctx = ClientContext(url).with_credentials(user_credentials)
    file_url = "Shared Documents/Messages/File_to_Download.xlsx"
    download_path = "x.xlsx"
    with open(download_path, "wb") as local_file:
        file = (
            ctx.web.get_file_by_server_relative_path(file_url)
            .download(local_file)
            .execute_query()
        )

The downloaded excel doesn't open. It throws an error saying
"Excel cannot be open the file 'filename.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid"
If I change the code to
download_path = "x.html"

The downloaded excel opens as a webpage in the browser.
How do I download it as an excel file ?
I have tried using openpyxl and reading the file as BytesIO which also throws a BadZipFile Error.
Can anyone please help.

Can you confirm that this file is actually an xlsx file? How was it created? Shared Documents/Messages/File_to_Download.xlsx

Yes. It is an xlsx file for sure. I , myself uploaded it to the location. @MH.

You could look at the source of the file you download in an editor. It could simply be a link. Can't you create a local link to the path on your machine?

@CharlieClark. This file is going to be uploaded to the sharepoint location once a week by another team. I need to run a cron job to parse it and do the processing. No way to take it from the source.

So what does it look like in an editor?

@CharlieClark. I am sorry but I dont understand how an excel file is of any importance ? If necessary , It is used for capacity planning , so it contains employee data and worked hours in a week.

Then your description is erroneous and we cannot help you.

I think there's some misunderstanding in the above conversation. I'll try help. 1) Charlie Clark is asking if you were to open the downloaded file in a program like VS code, what do you see? Is it a plain text file? (BTW if it is a real xlsx file, you can rename it as a .zip and open in winzip (or similar, and you will see various files and folders. This would confirm it is truly a xlsx file.

Charlies is suspecting the downloaded file is literally a text file with a url path to the real file. Again, check as per point 1.

...


the file is what it is, by downloading it "as" a .html file doesn't change the file. the file extension just tells your OS how to open it. So again, it is worth checking that the file is actually a xlsx file, if so, then the issue is still unresolved. (I've seen this exact error myself and curious as to the solution).


Thank you explaining. Yes , When I open it in a text editor , I can see the html code(Hence why I wrote that it is getting downloaded as a webpage). The layout of the page that is opened in the browser. My bad @CharlieClark for the misunderstanding.
